# Write Test case for check Date time by NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit

I can't test dates like day 1 on day 2 on day 3

```
public int dayInMonth(int month,int year)
    {
        if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
        {
            return 30;
        }
        else if (month == 2)
        {
            if (year % 400 == 0)
            {
                return 29;
            }
            else if (year % 100 == 0)
            {
                return 28;
            }
            else if (year % 4 == 0)
            {
                return 29;
            }
            else return 28;
        }
        else
        {
            return 31;
        }      
    }
```

I need to use NUnit to test it. But I don't know how to write test cases for this Method

Comment: Call the method with known inputs. Assert the result is what you expected.

Comment: Assert.AreEqual( expectResult, actualResult ); Check out [NUnit's doc](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.AreEqual)

Comment: The real question is why are you using this method at all? Why not `DateTime.DaysInMonth(2020, 2)`? Then you don't even need to test it because Microsoft already tested it.

Comment: If you insist on using your own method, and want to see what test cases Microsoft considered important, you can look [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/110282c71b3f7e1f91ea339953f4a0eba362a62c/src/libraries/System.Runtime/tests/System/DateTimeTests.cs#L261-L305).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break your test into three parts

Arrange, Act & Assert

For example

```
// Arrange
var someObject = new SomeClass();
var year = 2020;
var month = 2;
var expectedResult = 29;

// Act
var actualResult = someObject.dayInMonth(year, month);

// Assert
Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
```

As @John mentioned the example, when you need to run your test against multiple inputs use parameters to [TestCaseAttribute](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCase-Attribute)

**UPDATE:**

```
TestCaseAttribute example
[TestCase(2020, 1, ExpectedResult=31)]
[TestCase(2020, 2, ExpectedResult=29)]
[TestCase(2020, 3, ExpectedResult=31)]
public int DayInMonthTest(int year, int month)
{
    var someObject = new SomeClass();
    return someObject.dayInMonth(year, month);
}
```

Comment: But this way does not check the other day. For example, day 1, day 2, day 3

Comment: @QuýVõ What do you mean? The only possible dates to check for are 28, 29, 30, and 31, anything else is invalid.

Comment: @QuýVõ I believe you are looking to test your method with multiple inputs. If that is the case then please look at the update I made. Otherwise, please provide some more detail regarding what you want to achieve

Comment: @mhsarosh Yes, I'm looking to test your method with multiple inputs.

Comment: I want to test every day of the month, what should I do?

Comment: @QuýVõ your method dayInMonth doesn't expect and require the day of the month. Perhaps you need to update the logic in the method if it doesn't fulfill your requirement